# Installing M2Crypto on Windows

Tags: python, easy-install, m2crypto

I am trying to install M2Crypto on a Windows 7 machine using easy_install. However, I get the following error:

> SWIG_m2crypto.i(31) : Error: Unable to find 'openssl\opensslv.h'
>   SWIG_m2crypto.i(45) : Error: Unable to find 'openssl\safestack.h'
>   SWIG_evp.i(12) : Error: Unable to find 'openssl\opensslconf.h'
>   SWIG_ec.i(7) : Error: Unable to find 'openssl\opensslconf.h'
>   error: Setup script exited with error: command 'swig.exe' failed with exit status 1

Any advice?

i tried installing [openssl](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) for windows.

Comment: Install via pip: `pip install M2CryptoWin64` (for 64-bit Win) or `pip install M2CryptoWin32` (for 32-bit). See this [blog](http://the.randomengineer.com/2014/07/29/ssl-for-python-m2crypto-on-windows/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Windows Installer in the [M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto#Downloads) page.

Unable to install using `easy_install` on Windows.

Comment: _[M2Crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto#Downloads)_ is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Install [this M2Crypto binary for Windows 32 bit, Python 2.7](https://github.com/edwardt/windows-nova-client/blob/master/3rdParty/ActivePython-2.7.2.5-win32-x86.msi)

then open package manager and type:

> pypm install M2Crypto

(**NOTE:** Active Python 2.7.6 64 does not work here. Reason unknown.)

Comment: could you please post the M2Crypto binary? I can't find it in the link provided.

Comment: This is an old post, but the installer pointed to by the link above, is under the the _[View Raw](https://github.com/edwardt/windows-nova-client/blob/master/3rdParty/ActivePython-2.7.2.5-win32-x86.msi?raw=true)_ link at the bottom of its page.  (at least at the time I posted this comment)